# Add checkbox to each element

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

So I'm new at JavaScript and was struggling to add check boxes to each element inside the `div` with the `id` "userlist".

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="userlist">  //Here's the element with the ID "userlist"
<div class="user me" id="user_9a9pkmz43nkp6t3rr383xlzcj99xmi4m">
    <div class="buttonholder">
        <div class="button color" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"> 
</div>
        <div class="button tool eyes"></div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="usertext"><span class="username" style="text-decoration: none;">from Prairie Village, United States</span> <span id="chat">send chat msg</span></div>
</div>
<div class="user" id="user_7ku2rum35ko7nddwdpjd2c53zordfzzd">
    <div class="buttonholder">
        <div class="button color" title="click to show last line drawn by user" style="background-color: rgb(77, 255, 112);"></div>
        <div class="button tool eyes"></div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="usertext"><span class="username">Imp</span> <span class="ignore">ignore</span><span class="rename">rename</span></div>
</div>
<div class="user" id="user_id6rwedzewineum8t2f6xf2dbqejorfs" style="display: none;">
    <div class="buttonholder">
        <div class="button color" title="click to show last line drawn by user" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div>
        <div class="button tool eyes"></div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="usertext"><span class="username">from an unknown place</span> <span class="ignore">ignore</span><span class="rename">rename</span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

So somehow could I add a check box to each element with the class "user" and get the value of the ID of that class when the check box is checked, then log the value to console? So if it get's checked. It'll log that class's Id value?

This is what I've managed to scrape so far. I would like to use this basic layout in some way. Please note this doesn't work & this is why I'm here trying to get help. Please don't be too harsh on me.

```
var muteArray = {};
var users = document.getElementById("userlist");

users.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
muteArray = {};
for (let i = 0; i < users.childNodes.length; i++) {
if (users.childNodes[i].getElementsByClassName("mute")[0]) {
  if (users.childNodes[i].getElementsByClassName("mute")[0].checked) 
{
    console.log(muteArray) // Log the selected users Id value :( doesn't 
work.
  };
} else {

  let checkbox = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox.className = "mute";
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  checkbox.style.width = "30px";
  checkbox.style.height = "30px";
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      console.log("") //Maybe log Id's value here?
    } else {
      console.log("something")
    };
  });
  users.childNodes[i].insertBefore(checkbox, users.childNodes[i].getElementsByClassName("user")[0]);
};
```

So if a element's checkbox gets checked. Do a function. The function would be logging that class's Id value.

Comment: I'm not seeing where the checkboxes you're trying to add are? It looks like you're listening for `DOMSubtreeModified`, could you explain the purpose of that? Is it that the `.user` divs can get added to the `#userlist` dynamically, and you would like to add checkboxes to them when that happens?

Comment: That's correct. They can pop up anytime.

Comment: & when that happens. I would like to add a checkbox to the ``.user``

Comment: I've added my full script. I know it says don't do that but I hope you can help me now with this more information. I think you have the basic idea on what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: don't use DOMSubtreeModified event it's deprecated, use MutationObserver instead.

Answer (score 0):

First consider using MutationObserver instead of DOMSubtreeModified - MutationObserver is a lot faster, and DOMSubtreeModified is deprecated.

Inside the MutationObserver callback, use `querySelectorAll` to find `.user`s which do not have checkboxes yet. (To do this concisely, when adding a checkbox, add a `data-` attribute to the `.user`, so that `.user`s with that `data-` attribute do not get iterated over again in the future.) Just inserting the checkbox is enough for the callback.

To listen for checkbox change events on dynamically inserted elements, use event delegation: listen for `change` events on the *parent*, the `userlist`. Checkboxes checked inside the userlist will fire events which will bubble up to the userlist, and the listener can check to see if the event fired was from one of the elements your userscript created - if so, just navigate from the event target (the checkbox) to its parent, and then you can log the parent's ID.

```js
const userlist = document.querySelector('#userlist');
new MutationObserver(() => {
  userlist.querySelectorAll('.user:not([data-has-checkbox])').forEach((userDiv) => {
    const checkbox = userDiv.insertBefore(document.createElement('input'), userDiv.children[0]);
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    userDiv.dataset.hasCheckbox = true;
  });
}).observe(userlist, { childList: true });

userlist.innerHTML = `
  <div class="user me" id="user_9a9pkmz43nkp6t3rr383xlzcj99xmi4m"><div>content 1</div></div>
  <div class="user" id="user_7ku2rum35ko7nddwdpjd2c53zordfzzd"><div>content 2</div></div>
  <div class="user" id="user_id6rwedzewineum8t2f6xf2dbqejorfs" style="display: none;"><div>content 3</div></div>
`;

setTimeout(() => {
  userlist.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'beforeend',
    `<div class="user" id="user_7ku2rum35ko7nddwdpjd2c53zordfzzd"><div>content 4</div></div>`
  );
}, 2500);

userlist.addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.matches('.user > input[type="checkbox"]')) {
    const userDiv = target.parentElement;
    console.log(userDiv.id);
  }
});
```

```css
.user {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="userlist">

</div>
```

Comment: So i'm trying to make my request send only if the check box is checked.. When I un-check it, it sends the request??

Comment: Or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771258/send-post-request-only-if-check-box-is-checked

Comment: To check whether the checkbox was just checked or unchecked, check its `checked` property: `target.checked`

Comment: Can you take a look at my question here please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771258/send-post-request-only-if-check-box-is-checked

Comment: It's dealing with your piece of code as well. Maybe you can understand and help me better.