# Send POST request only if check box is checked

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

So I'm trying to make my script only log and send the POST request if the check box is checked... The problem is when I un-check the box. It's still sending the post request.

This script basically adds check boxes to a specific elements, and gets the ID value if it's checked.

Here's my script:

```
const userlist = document.querySelector('#userlist');
new MutationObserver(() => {
userlist.querySelectorAll('.user:not([data-has-checkbox])').forEach((userDiv) => {
const checkbox = userDiv.insertBefore(document.createElement('input'), userDiv.children[0]);
checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
userDiv.dataset.hasCheckbox = true;
});
}).observe(userlist, { childList: true });

userlist.addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => {
if (target.matches('.user > input[type="checkbox"]')) {
const userDiv = target.parentElement;
var nameb = userDiv.id.replace("user_", ""); // Make variable for REQUEST
}

var evtSource = new EventSource("http://myurl.com/_watch//_index?_=1557958948927");

evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
var obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
var line = JSON.stringify(obj.line)
var size = JSON.stringify(obj.lineWidth)
var color = JSON.stringify(obj.lineColor) // Not needed, but defined 
anyways.
var chat = JSON.stringify(obj.msg)
var original = line
//var mirror = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original).replace(/\d+/g, number => 20 + +number))
var list = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userList)) //LineLog


//--------------------------



if (obj.ident === nameb) // if ident ='s userDiv's Id value...
{
$.post("/draw.php?ing=_index", {
           l: (line),
           w : parseInt(obj.lineWidth) + 2,
           c: ("ffffff"),
            o: ("100"),
            f: ("1"),
            _: ("false")
})
console.log(nameb) //log the value.
}
});
```

If you can help me find a solution that would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
const checkbox = document.querySelector('#myCheckBox');

checkbox.addEventListener('change', e => {
    const self = e.target;
    if (self.checked){
        // send
    }
})
```

```
const userlist = document.querySelector('#userlist');
new MutationObserver(() => {
userlist.querySelectorAll('.user:not([data-has-checkbox])').forEach((userDiv) => {
const checkbox = userDiv.insertBefore(document.createElement('input'), userDiv.children[0]);
checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
userDiv.dataset.hasCheckbox = true;
});
}).observe(userlist, { childList: true });

userlist.addEventListener('change', (e, { target }) => {
if ( !e.target.checked ) return
if (target.matches('.user > input[type="checkbox"]')) {
const userDiv = target.parentElement;
var nameb = userDiv.id.replace("user_", "");
}

var evtSource = new EventSource("http://myurl.com/_watch//_index?_=1557958948927");

evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
var obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
var line = JSON.stringify(obj.line)
var size = JSON.stringify(obj.lineWidth)
var color = JSON.stringify(obj.lineColor) // Not needed, but defined 
anyways.
var chat = JSON.stringify(obj.msg)
var original = line
//var mirror = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original).replace(/\d+/g, number => 20 + +number))
var list = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userList)) //LineLog


//--------------------------



if (obj.ident === nameb) // if ident ='s userDiv's Id value...
{
$.post("/draw.php?ing=_index", {
           l: (line),
           w : parseInt(obj.lineWidth) + 2,
           c: ("ffffff"),
            o: ("100"),
            f: ("1"),
            _: ("false")
})
console.log(nameb) //log the value.
}
});
```

Comment: Says e is not defined.

Comment: ok... try it now. your code is really huge and complex for a simple code.